# Convert all hex in a string to its char value in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

In Redshift, I'm trying to convert strings like this:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FTest%3Fname%3DGary%26Bob
```

To look like this:

```
http://www.amazon.com/Test?name=Gary&Bob
```

Basically I need to convert all of the hex in a string to its char value. The only way I can think of is to use a regex function. I tried to do it in two different ways and received error messages for both:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(hex_string, '%([[:xdigit:]][[:xdigit:]])', CHR(x'\\1'::int))
ERROR: 22P02: "\" is not a valid hexadecimal digit

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(hex_string, '%([[:xdigit:]][[:xdigit:]])',CHR(STRTOL('0x'||'\\1', 16)::int))
ERROR: 22023: The input 0x\1 is not valid to be converted to base 16
```

The CHR and STRTOL functions works by itself. For example:

```
SELECT CHR(x'3A'::int)
SELECT CHR(STRTOL('0x3A', 16)::int)
```

both returns

```
:
```

And if I run the same pattern using a different function (other than CHR and STRTOL), it works:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(hex_string, '%([[:xdigit:]][[:xdigit:]])', LOWER('{H}'||'\\1'||'{/H}'))
```

returns

```
http{h}3A{/h}{h}2F{/h}{h}2F{/h}www.amazon.com{h}2F{/h}Test{h}3F{/h}name{h}3D{/h}Gary{h}26{/h}Bob
```

But for some reason those functions won't recognize the regex matching group.

Any tips on how I can do this?

I guess the other solution is to use nested REPLACE() functions for all of the special hex characters, but that's probably a very last resort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is called "URL decode".

Currently there is no built-in function for doing this, but you can create a custom [User-Defined Function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/user-defined-functions.html) (make sure you have the required [privileges](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-security-and-privileges.html)):

```
CREATE FUNCTION urldecode(url VARCHAR)
RETURNS varchar
IMMUTABLE AS $$
  import urllib
  return urllib.unquote(url).decode('utf8')  # or 'latin-1', depending on how the text is encoded
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Example query:

```
SELECT urldecode('http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FTest%3Fname%3DGary%26Bob');
```

Result:

```
http://www.amazon.com/Test?name=Gary&Bob
```

Comment: This worked, thank you so much! 

Just an FYI, I got this error message when running it on some longer strings:  ERROR: XX000: Value too long for character type. 

I changed the function to use the maximum varchar(65535) and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Some of my data threw this error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xec in position 4468: invalid continuation byte.  I resolved it by changing my encoding to latin-1 instead of utf8.

Comment: @NghiLe: Thanks for the update. I added this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried @hiddenbit's answer in REDSHIFT, but Python 3 isn't supported. The following Py2 code did work for me, however:

```
DROP FUNCTION urldecode(varchar);
CREATE FUNCTION urldecode(url VARCHAR)
RETURNS varchar
IMMUTABLE AS $$
  import urllib
  return urllib.unquote(url)
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```